# React component not updating on changes to map (data structure) in redux state store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've a map stored in redux state store and a react component which renders the values that I've stored in the map. Now when I'm adding/removing values from this map, my react component does not update itself with the latest changes.

NOTE: I saw that we can use `mobX` module to listen to changes in map (or other data structures other than array), but I don't want to use another module or so to achieve this.

My Redux store

```
const initialState = {
    myNotes = new Map();
}
```

My Reducer

```
case CREATE_NEW_NOTE:
      const { noteAdded, success } = action.payload;
      let newOwnerNotes = state.myNotes;

      newOwnerNotes.set(noteAdded.note_id, noteAdded);

      if (success) {
        return {
          ...state,
          myNotes: newOwnerNotes
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state
        };
      }
case DELETE_NOTE:
      const noteIdToDelete = action.payload.note_id;
      const { success } = action.payload;
      let newState = Object.assign({}, state);

      if (success) {
        newState.myNotes.delete(noteIdToDelete);
        return {
          ...newState
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state
        };
      }
```

My React Component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Components
import Notes from "../notes/Notes";
import Heading from "./Heading";

class Owner extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { myNotes } = this.props;
    debugger;
    return (
      <div className="notes-owner">
        <div className="notes-owner-header">
          <Heading owner={true} />
        </div>
        <div className="notes-owner-content">
          {[...myNotes].map(([key, note]) => {
            return (
              <Notes note={note} owner={true} key={note.note_id}>
                {note.title}
              </Notes>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    myNotes: state.notes.myNotes
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Owner);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `Map`, at least not like this. You are mutating the state. Look at this line:

```
  let newOwnerNotes = state.myNotes;

  newOwnerNotes.set(noteAdded.note_id, noteAdded);
```

You are just referencing the same object. Try like this:

```
  let newOwnerNotes = new Map(state.myNotes);

  newOwnerNotes.set(noteAdded.note_id, noteAdded);
```

You should remember always that arrays, objects, maps, are all `reference types`, look at the following snippet:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
const copy = arr
const realCopy = [...arr]
console.log(copy, realCopy) //[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(copy === arr) //true
console.log(realCopy === arr) //false
```

When you just assign like `const copy = arr` you are not creating another array, you are just referencing the same object, but in the second situation (using the spread operator) you are creating another array wich contains the spread of all items from `arr`. See more about [immutability in JS](https://medium.com/dailyjs/the-state-of-immutability-169d2cd11310) here.

When you do `const newNotes = new Map(state.myNotes)` you are creating another Object, now you do your modifications and in the end: `return {...state, myNotes: newOwnerNotes};`

Comment: I've updated the question with the right way to """copy""" the old Map object

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow